# Prove the relation $R$ in $N \times N$ defined by $(a,b) \simeq (c,d)$ iff $ad=bc$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

If $N$ is the set of all natural numbers, $R$ is a relation on $N \times N$, defined by $(a,b) \simeq (c,d)$ iff $ad=bc$, how can I prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation ?

Comment: What do you know about equivalence relations?  Do you consider $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ or do you consider $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$?  If the first, what is related to $(0,0)$?  Otherwise, what do you know about the terms reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity?  Does this relation satisfy those?

Comment: Do you know the three properties of an equivalence relation?

Comment: As an aside, if we exclude zero, this relation should remind you a great deal of how we talk about fractions being equal.  $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{6} = \frac{5}{10} = \dots$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To prove that this is an equivalence relation, you must prove reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.  Each of these is a different statement that you must prove.

- Reflexivity: Suppose that $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.  Then, you want to prove that $(a,b)R(a,b)$.  This can get a little confusing because sometimes a relation is written as a pair - so students sometimes consider the case where $a=b$, i.e., $(a,a)$.  If you want to write a relation in terms of a pair, you would write $((a,b),(a,b))$.
- Symmetry: Suppose that $(a,b),(c,d)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ such that $(a,b)R(c,d)$ (so $ad=bc$).  Now, you would like to prove $(c,d)R(a,b)$, in other words that $cb=da$.  This can get a little confusing because students sometimes try to look at symmetry of $(a,b)$, in other words, look at $(b,a)$.  Since the objects are in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, you want to reverse the two elements of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.
- Transitivity: Suppose that $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ such that $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(e,f)$; in other words, you know that $ad=bc$ and $cf=de$.  You would like to prove $(a,b)R(e,f)$, in other words, that $af=be$.  If you manipulate $ab=bc$ by multiplying both sides by $f$, you get the desired $(af)b$ on the LHS.  Now, use the other equality on the RBS and divide by $b$ (is $b\not=0$!?)

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it step by step:

$$\forall (a,b)\in \Bbb{N}\times \Bbb{N}^{*},\, ab=ab$$

So $(a,b)\mathcal{R}(a,b)$ and $\mathcal{R}$ is **reflexive**.

Assume now that $(a,b)\mathcal{R}(c,d)$ i.e $ad=bc$. Multiplication is commutative so we can write $cb=da$ and this gives $(c,d)\mathcal{R}(a,b)$. The relation is **symmetric**

Now take $(a,b)\mathcal{R}(c,d)$ and $(c,d)\mathcal{R}(e,f)$ ; this means $ad=bc$ and $cf=de$.
Multiply the first equality by $f\neq 0$ to get $afd=bcf$ and the second by $b\neq 0$ to get $bcf=bed$. So we have $afd=bed$ and keeping in mind $d\neq 0$ we have $af=be$ i.e $(a,b)\mathcal{R}(e,f)$ and the relation is **transitive**

It is therefore an equivalence relation

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You need to prove that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

I leave the first two to you. They are very straight forward.

Now suppose $(a,b) \simeq (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \simeq (e,f)$

Then $ad = bc$ and $cf=de$

Thus

$(ad)(cf)=(bc)(de)$

and by cancelling from both sides

$af=be$

Accordingly $(a,b) \simeq (e,f)$ and $R$ is transitive.

Comment: It should be mentioned, depending on the definition of $\Bbb N$, the "cancelling" step is potentially not allowed.  (*cannot divide by zero.  In fact, it will not be an equivalence relation if zero is considered an element of $\Bbb N$*)

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, and therefore i assumed 0 is not in the set.